# How do I remove the default post type from the admin toolbar

Tags: custom-post-types

We're configuring a new WordPress to use custom post types, and we want our editors to log in and only see only the custominzed post types, not the default 'post' post type. We've been able to remove 'post' from the Admin menu using [this trick](https://www.techjunkie.com/remove-default-post-type-from-admin-menu-wordpress/), but that still leaves the "+ New" Admin toolbar button, which contains a post option and defaults to creating a post. Is there an easy and safe way to remove post from the *new* toolbar button and/or hide the *new* toolbar button?

Comment: If you remove the posts related capabilities from the Editor role (or whichever you're using) these options shouldn't appear.

Comment: If the post type refuses to unregister, and if the "register_post_type" function isn't in functions.php, see if the registration is saved in a "must use plugin". As a reminder I place this comment at the top of my functoins.php "/* if something is stuck, look in must use plugins!!! */"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to hook to 3 different action hooks to fully hide the default post type. However, a direct access to the default post by URL is still possible. So, let's get started.

### The Side Menu

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_default_post_type' );

function remove_default_post_type() {
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
}
```

### The + New > Post link in Admin Bar

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_default_post_type_menu_bar', 999 );

function remove_default_post_type_menu_bar( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-post' );
}
```

### The + New link in Admin Bar

```
function remove_add_new_post_href_in_admin_bar() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function remove_add_new_post_href_in_admin_bar() {
            var add_new = document.getElementById('wp-admin-bar-new-content');
            if(!add_new) return;
            var add_new_a = add_new.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
            if(add_new_a) add_new_a.setAttribute('href','#!');
        }
        remove_add_new_post_href_in_admin_bar();
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'remove_add_new_post_href_in_admin_bar' );


function remove_frontend_post_href(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'remove_add_new_post_href_in_admin_bar' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_frontend_post_href' );
```

### The Quick Draft Dashboard Widget

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_draft_widget', 999 );

function remove_draft_widget(){
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side' );
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way, although the `New` button in the admin bar still points to `post-new.php` - can be disabled with some Javascript e.g. `$(document).on('click', '#wp-admin-bar-new-content', function(){ return false })`

Comment: This seems faultlessly working, but: "At a glance" still shows the posts (and it doesn't show the CPTs in any case!), just like the "Next Steps" part of the "Welcome to WP" dashboard item [which I hate and dismiss anyway]. Also "Activity" might still show posts, but shouldn't if you set it up neatly.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative, but similar solution to Stefan and Rafa's. This does not throw errors, and notice if you navigate directly to /wp-admin/edit.php you will not be able to view the list of posts (default post type), or edit them.

Note this code does not actually disable the default post type, i.e. existing post types will still be published and accessible via public URL. It effectively disables backend access to the default post type for all users.

```
function remove_default_post_type($args, $postType) {
    if ($postType === 'post') {
        $args['public']                = false;
        $args['show_ui']               = false;
        $args['show_in_menu']          = false;
        $args['show_in_admin_bar']     = false;
        $args['show_in_nav_menus']     = false;
        $args['can_export']            = false;
        $args['has_archive']           = false;
        $args['exclude_from_search']   = true;
        $args['publicly_queryable']    = false;
        $args['show_in_rest']          = false;
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'remove_default_post_type', 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

In principle it is possible to unregister already registered post types using `unregister_post_type()`. Unfortunately this is not possible for `_builtin` post types.

Alternatively it is possible to change the capabilities which are required to edit/create/delete/... posts for a specific post type. You could use the `register_post_type_args` filter to change the capabilities which are required for the default `post` post type. Setting all capabilities to `false` will result in nobody having access to the default post post type. WordPress is smart enough to automatically hide the navigation entries.

```
add_filter('register_post_type_args', function($args, $postType){
    if ($postType === 'post') {
        $args['capabilities'] = [
            'edit_post' => false,
            'read_post' => false,
            'delete_post' => false,
            'edit_posts' => false,
            'edit_others_posts' => false,
            'publish_posts' => false,
            'read' => false,
            'delete_posts' => false,
            'delete_private_posts' => false,
            'delete_published_posts' => false,
            'delete_others_posts' => false,
            'edit_private_posts' => false,
            'edit_published_posts' => false,
            'create_posts' => false,
        ];
    }

    return $args
}, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I put this code into a function that was fired on the 'init' event, but it didn't seem to have any effect on my UI. Am I hooking the wrong event?

Comment: That is too late. WordPress registers all `_builtin` post types at the `init` action but with an priority of `0`.

The code above is registering just a filter, you do not have to put it inside another action/filter, just write it directly into your themes `functions.php` for example.

Comment: +1. The thing is it throws 3 notices. "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 70". I couldn't get rid of them.

Comment: Note that this doesn't remove the "category" and "post_tag" taxonomies, so the "Posts" nav menu item remains (albeit without letting you view or edit posts themselves.)

Answer (score 0):

Stefan's solution is great, but if you active debug you can see :
Undefined offset: 0 in wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 62
plus there is a missing ; after return $args

Exhaustive code should be :

```
add_filter('register_post_type_args', function($args, $postType){
    if ($postType === 'post' && current_user_can( 'create_posts' ) && current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) {
        $args['capabilities'] = [
            'edit_post' => false,
            'read_post' => false,
            'delete_post' => false,
            'edit_posts' => false,
            'edit_others_posts' => false,
            'publish_posts' => false,
            'read' => false,
            'delete_posts' => false,
            'delete_private_posts' => false,
            'delete_published_posts' => false,
            'delete_others_posts' => false,
            'edit_private_posts' => false,
            'edit_published_posts' => false,
            'create_posts' => false,
        ];
    }
    return $args;
}, 0, 2);
```

Comment: current_user_can throws an error. It is not defined yet at this stage.